# Very new to Javascript OOP: Passing a value to property through input fails to render single Element

Tags: javascript

I'm having problems rendering individual "li" elements through OOP approach.

I'm fetching the input from the user and using this info to create an item through a class. I'm then connecting this class to the list class responsible for rendering the list.

Once I fetch the value through a click event listener, the singleTaskRendering class isn't working. I wonder if I'm setting this up incorrectly?

```
const inputAccess = document.querySelector('.control').querySelector('input');  
const addItemBtnAccess = document.getElementById('add-item-btn'); 

const toDoList = []; 
const doneList = []; 

//ads a li id to the item 
const idGenerator = (array) => {
  let n = 1;
  let message = ''; 
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
     n += 1; 
  }
  message = `li-${n}`; 
  return message; 
}

class ItemTask {
  constructor(itemValue, idGen) {
    this.title = itemValue; 
    this.id = idGen; 
  }
}


const addItemBtnHandler = () => {
  const toDoList = []; 
  const inputValue = inputAccess.value; 
  const item= new ItemTask(inputValue, idGenerator(toDoList));
  toDoList.push(item);
  return toDoList;
}; 

class singleTaskRendering {
  constructor(product) {
    this.product = product;  
  }

  render() {
    const titleElement = document.createElement('div'); 
    titleElement.id = this.product.id; 
      titleElement.innerHTML = `
        <li>
          <h2>${this.product.title}</h2>
          <button>Done</button>
          <button>Delete</button>
        </li>`; 
      titleElement.draggable = true;
  }
}

class ItemLists {
  constructor(listId, items) {
    this.items = items; 
    this.listId = listId; 
    console.log(this.items, this.listId); 
  }
  renderList() {

    const renderHook = document.getElementById('hook'); 
    const createList = document.createElement('lu'); 
    createList.className = 'card'; 
    createList.id = `${this.listId}-list`;
      for(let item of this.items) {
        const newItem = new singleTaskRendering(item); 
        console.log(newItem); 
        const itemEl = newItem.render(); 
        console.log(itemEl, newItem); 
        createList.apppend(itemEl); 
      }
  renderHook.append(createList); 
  }
}

const itemList = new ItemLists('active', toDoList); 
itemList.renderList(); 

addItemBtnAccess.addEventListener('click', addItemBtnHandler);
```

Comment: Although this isn't your problem, I would recommend changing this: `document.querySelector('.control').querySelector('input')` to `document.querySelector('.control input')`. It still accomplishes the same thing, its just a little cleaner.

Comment: The problem that you are having is that you call `ItemLists` on page load, which means it will only be processing an empty `toDoList`.

Comment: Thanks, I see... that is what I was thinking, should I initialize it on the event listener? 

Yes, I thought it was too messy, the access :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem that you are having is that you call `ItemLists` on page load, which means it will only be processing an empty `toDoList`.

- My solution is to rename renderList to appendItem.
- Declare it at the top
- Don't pass the list id and list to the constructor instead pass it to
  appendItem in the clickhandler.

  ```
   const inputAccess = document.querySelector('.control').querySelector('input');  
   const addItemBtnAccess = document.getElementById('add-item-btn'); 
   const itemList = new ItemLists(); 

   const toDoList = []; 
   const doneList = []; 

   //ads a li id to the item 
   const idGenerator = (array) => {
     let n = 1;
     let message = ''; 
     for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        n += 1; 
     }
     message = `li-${n}`; 
     return message; 
   }

   class ItemTask {
     constructor(itemValue, idGen) {
       this.title = itemValue; 
       this.id = idGen; 
     }
   }


   const addItemBtnHandler = () => {
     const toDoList = []; 
     const inputValue = inputAccess.value; 
     const item= new ItemTask(inputValue, idGenerator(toDoList));
     itemList.appendItem('active', item); 
   }; 

   class singleTaskRendering {
     constructor(product) {
       this.product = product;  
     }

     render() {
       const titleElement = document.createElement('div'); 
       titleElement.id = this.product.id; 
         titleElement.innerHTML = `
           <li>
             <h2>${this.product.title}</h2>
             <button>Done</button>
             <button>Delete</button>
           </li>`; 
         titleElement.draggable = true;
     }
   }

   class ItemLists {

    appendItem(listId, item) {

       const renderHook = document.getElementById('hook'); 
       const createList = document.createElement('lu'); 
       createList.className = 'card'; 
       createList.id = `${listId}-list`;
           const newItem = new singleTaskRendering(item); 
           console.log(newItem); 
           const itemEl = newItem.render(); 
           console.log(itemEl, newItem); 
           createList.apppend(itemEl); 
     renderHook.append(createList); 
     }
   }

   addItemBtnAccess.addEventListener('click', addItemBtnHandler);
  ```

Comment: Thank you! you gave me a great idea pal!! :)